# Android R.string ids mix in multi-module tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-multi-module

My app is implemented as a multi-module project (with dynamics module), where there is a shared module with espresso tests. These espresso tests give me different outcomes depending if I run them from Android Studio or from the command line.

The issue I find when I run the tests from the command line is that it tries to assert against the wrong string resources.

The actual tests code is asserting this, where `R.string.home_activity_title` value is "Hello":

```
assertDisplayed(R.string.home_activity_title)
```

However when it is run from the command line, the assertion fails with this output

```
No views in hierarchy found matching: with string from resource id: <2131886676>[send_message_hint] value: Type a message…
```

Notice how the tests from the command line is trying to assert against a different string that the one is defined on the test.

I tried to understand the difference between running the tests from AndroidStudio and running them from the command line but I am clearly missing something here. This is how I run the tests from the command line

```
apk="path/to/apk"
testApk="path/to/test/apk"
testRunner="my.custom.test.runner"

# Generate universal APK
echo "Generating universal APK"
sh build_develop.sh

# Install universal APK on emulator
echo "Installing universal APK"
adb uninstall <appPackage>
adb install -t $apk

echo "Building test APK"
./gradlew :testModule:assembleDebugAndroidTest

echo "Installing Test APK"
adb uninstall <testApkPackage>
adb install -t $testApk

echo "Running Acceptance Tests"
# Run all acceptance tests
adb shell am instrument -w $testRunner
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the module for which you want the string to be obtained.
E.g. `com.example.module.R.string.home_activity_title` instead of `R.string.home_activity_title`

Comment: I tried that, the output changes slightly (it makes reference to a different string id) but there is still a miss match between what is asserting against and what it should be